# Select multiple items in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, select, jtextpane

I would like to highlight(select) multiple occurrences of a string in `JTextPane`. I would like to make something like findall. Here is what I have written.

```
 int a=0;
 while(jTextPane1.getText().indexOf(search,a)>0)
 {
     int i =jTextPane1.getText().indexOf(search,a);
     a=i+search.length();
     jTextPane1.select(i,a);
 }
```

It works ok, but the problem is that it highlights only the last occurrence, because the highlight changes. I would like to make multiple highlights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that tutorial about [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/jcomponent.html) contains detailed descriptions about that

- you have extract [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) from [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/jcomponent.html),
- then you can styled text into [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html), basically there are two ways use [Highlighter and StyledDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9651404/714968)
- for Html formatted text, you have to create own [HtlmEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.Parser.html)

Comment: The `TextFieldDemo` as described in the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) is the sample you are looking for, which basically does what @mKorbel described