# Java : getting the proper StartOffset for multiple text color in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, highlight, jtextpane

I need to create a program that accepts a string input and  will highlight certain words that is in my String List.

Example:

```
String MyList[] = {"Dog","Cat","Lion"};

Sample Input Text: I have a Dog and a Cat and a Lion . "
```

I dont have problem if the input text doesn't have any new line or escape character but if the input text have new line, this is the result.

Example:

```
String MyList[] = {"Dog","Cat","Lion"};
```

Sample Input Text:

```
I have a Dog 
and a Cat
and a Lion
```

**Note: The uppercase character means highligthed character**

```
I have a DOG
and a cAT
and a liON
```

My Sample Code for Highlighting:

```
for(String x : MyList)
{

int startOffset = inputText.indexOf(x);
doc.setCharacterAttributes  (startOffset,x.length,myStyle,false);


}
```

I guess the problem is the Newline or escape character but I can't find a way to fix it.

How can I get the correct start offset of the word if ever the input string have new line/s?

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

- AFAIK this is possible from `Document`,
- `Document` is `Model` for `JTextComponents`
- For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9878360/230513)