# Highlight one specific row/line in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, highlight, jtextarea

I am trying to highlight just one specific row in `JTextArea`, but I have no idea as to going about it. I need to get the specific row and then highlight it. I've read the other posts, but I still do not understand how to bring it together to solve my problem...help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Had you tried this wonderful POST, [How to highlight by @mKorbel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650992/how-to-change-text-color-in-the-jtextarea/9651404#9651404)

Comment: -1 for not researching this.  First thing that popped on google was a code snippet that worked.

Comment: I tried those but they do not solve my problem of highlighting a specific row , i'm trying to get a specific row and highlight it

Comment: *"still do not understand"*  Do you understand how to ask a question?  If so, please add one, and make it specific.  *"they do not solve my problem of highlighting a specific row"*  That only makes sense if the lines do not word-wrap.  As an aside, if you 'cannot get it working' you are best off posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best effort.  I can't see that anyone capable of doing so, will spoon-feeding the answer to this very specific question.

Comment: The question is Highlight one specific row/line in JTextArea

Comment: I've tried those links you posted up guys already before coming here, @AndrewThompson

Comment: *"I've tried those links you posted"*  1) Nobody but me was notified of that comment. 2) **We are not psychic.**  For that reason, it is a damn good idea to mention what you have tried, the threads you looked at, why they did not fulfill the spec. (etc.).  ***SO is not a help-desk, but a Q&A site.  The better specified question gets the better answer.***

Comment: @Jeffrey Odametey what did you talking about ???, do you joking ??? what do you expecting ???, I leaving this one for whales ...

Comment: Any more help will be much appreciated thnks guys. I'm a newbie at the graphics, i'm just trying to solve a little problem out of my program.I have no clue as to how to solve this one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try your hands on this code example, and do ask if something is not clear :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextHighlight
{
    private JTextArea tarea;
    private JComboBox cbox;
    private JTextField lineField;
    private String[] colourNames = {"RED", "ORANGE", "CYAN"};

    private Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter;

    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Text HIGHLIGHT");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5), "Highlighter JTextArea"));

        tarea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tarea);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        JButton button = new JButton("HIGHLIGHT TEXT");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                int selection = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                        frame, getOptionPanel(), "Highlighting Options : ", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION
                                                , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                if (selection == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)                             
                {
                    System.out.println("OK Selected");
                    int lineNumber = Integer.parseInt(lineField.getText().trim());
                    try
                    {
                        int startIndex = tarea.getLineStartOffset(lineNumber);
                        int endIndex = tarea.getLineEndOffset(lineNumber);
                        String colour = (String) cbox.getSelectedItem();

                        if (colour == colourNames[0])
                        {
                            System.out.println("RED Colour");
                            painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.RED);
                            tarea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(startIndex, endIndex, painter);
                        }
                        else if (colour == colourNames[1])
                        {
                            System.out.println("ORANGE Colour");
                            painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.ORANGE);
                            tarea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(startIndex, endIndex, painter);
                        }
                        else if (colour == colourNames[2])
                        {
                            System.out.println("CYAN Colour");
                            painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.CYAN);
                            tarea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(startIndex, endIndex, painter);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(BadLocationException ble)
                    {
                        ble.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else if (selection == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
                {
                    System.out.println("CANCEL Selected");
                }
                else if (selection == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION)
                {
                    System.out.println("JOptionPane closed deliberately.");
                }
            }
        });

        frame.add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getOptionPanel()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 5));

        JLabel lineNumberLabel = new JLabel("Enter Line Number : ");
        lineField = new JTextField(10);

        JLabel colourLabel = new JLabel("Select One Colour : ");
        cbox = new JComboBox(colourNames);

        panel.add(lineNumberLabel);
        panel.add(lineField);
        panel.add(colourLabel);
        panel.add(cbox);

        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new TextHighlight().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the output of it  :

[image: HIGHLIGHTER EXAMPLE]

Comment: thanks for your example code this is what I did instead.
`code
RectanglePainter red = new RectanglePainter( Color.RED );
            try {
f1.textarea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(f1.textarea.getLineStartOffset(iline), f1.textarea.getLineEndOffset(iline), red);//
            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
`

Answer (score 3):

If you are unable to select TextArea to TextField reason is button click causes the JTextArea to lose focus and thus not show its selection.
on button click event use `btnImport.transferFocusBackward();` to resolve issue.

Answer (score 0):

do like that :
this is the text area swing of java

```
JTextArea area = new JTextArea(); 
int startIndex = area.getLineStartOffset(2);
int endIndex = area.getLineEndOffset(2);
painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.RED);
area.getHighlighter().addHighlight(startIndex, endIndex, painter);
```