# How can i change the colour of certain words in a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

I'm making myself a little messenger just for fun. And I want to make it so that when you see a certain word in there, for example your username it will be blue.

for example it will look something like this:

**User1:**  Hello how are you?
User2:  I'm fine thanks, what about you :)

(bold = blue, not bold = black)

This is how my client looks at the moment:
[image: The window]

Anyway.. I hope this information will be enough for you to understand my question/ problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Please have a look at this example, [How to colour specific Text Literels using JTextPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650992/how-to-change-text-color-in-the-jtextarea/9652143#9652143)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid that `JTextArea` cannot contain HTML tags to change text color. It was designed to store plain text only. You might have to use `JTextPane`. Official info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html