# How to set font color for selected text in jTextArea?

Tags: java, jtextarea

I have to set defined color(like red) for selected text in jTextArea. It is like highlighting process in text area (jTextArea). When I select particular text and click on any button it should change in predefined color.

I can change jTextArea to jTextPane or JEditorPane if there is any solution.

Comment: Show us code that you have tried so far.

Comment: `JTextPane` or `JEditorPane` may be a better option for you here.

Comment: Thanks berry I can change it to jTextPane or jEditorPane if there is any solution.

Comment: Your answer, with working example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650992/how-to-change-text-color-in-the-jtextarea

Comment: EnKrypt, I tried with jTextArea1.setSelectedTextColor(Color.red); but that change color when I am selecting particular text. I want to set it fixed until I close window, like highlighter.

Comment: @Spiker did you check the link and the accepted answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Styled text (with a color attribute for characters) is available as StyledDocument, and usable in JTextPane and JEditorPane. So use a JTextPane.

```
private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
    int start = textPane.getSelectionStart();
    int end = textPane.getSelectionEnd();
    if (start == end) { // No selection, cursor position.
        return;
    }
    if (start > end) { // Backwards selection?
        int life = start;
        start = end;
        end = life;
    }
    Style style = textPane.addStyle("MyHilite", null);
    StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.GREEN.darker());
    //style = textPane.getStyle("MyHilite");
    doc.setCharacterAttributes(start, end - start, style, false);
}
```

Mind: the style can be set at the creation of the JTextPane, and as the outcommented code shows, retrieved out of the JTextPane field.

Comment: Thank you, I think this code works. How to use StyledDocument and other style in it? it is showing "Can not find symbol".

Comment: There must be a JTextPane textPane, and `import javax.swing.text.*`. And then there is somewhere JButton with addActionListener or so.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can not do this using JTextArea because it is a plain text area.You have to use a styled text area like JEditorPane.see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html).You can use a HTMLDocument and do what you want.See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html)