# How to draw line in JTextArea and change color of a specific words

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm currently developing JTextArea with a Notepad++ like function (currently indentation function finished).

Now I'm trying to add a function which in  my JTextArea will show a dotted line for an indentation with same level, and change specific color of a word.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Nope, I don't have a clue on drawing color inside JTextArea.
I tried to change JTextArea forecolor but it affects all the words.

Comment: a dotted line for an indentation with same level, and change specific color of a word. are you meaning underline

Comment: No, not an underline, but a straight vertical line.

Comment: Here is one related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9650992/1057230). If I understood the concept, I guess you might want to create an application which is similar to `JEdit/Notepad2/Notepad++`, then I guess you can use the concept of `JTree`, since that will allow you to fold your function definition as an when required, as seen in many advance IDEs now a days :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not able to achieve  your target with JTextArea as it is a plain text support component.You have to use a Styled text supported JEditorPane or JTextPane.And try to use a HTML document and achieve it.Look at

[Styled supported components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html)

and

[some more examples](http://java-sl.com/tip_autocreate_links.html)