# Changing Font in JTextArea for new text only

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextarea, styledtext

I am using a `JTextArea` for a text editor program. 
Text in the text area is provisionally set in the constructor using:

```
teaxtArea.setFont("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14);
```

I have added event handlers that allow user to select various font styles and sizes. 
However when the new changes are applied via the `setFont` method the text already in the text area is changed.

Is it possible to apply the new font to new text only?

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9651404/1057230) by @mKorbel, I hope it helps :-) Though you need a [JTextPane/JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) for this sort of thingy to work.

Comment: *"Thanks Ciaran"*  Don't include sigs. in questions.  They are noise.

Comment: crossposted on Coderanch