# Multiple Text Colors in a scrollpane?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jscrollpane, scrollpane

This is my gui that I have right now, I need the scroll pane to display green on a win and red on a loss. Is it possible? Because, I might be able to color it before it is sent to the scrollpane right?

Here is the code for the scroll pane part.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import json.JsonObject;
public class dicebot extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static String APIKey = null;
    public static JComboBox<String>cmbCurrency;
    public static JButton btnLow;
    public static JButton btnFloat;
    public static JButton btnHigh;
    public static JButton btnClearLog;
    public static JButton btnDonate;
    public static JTextPane textPane;
    public static JCheckBox scrollCheck;
    public static JCheckBox scrollDisable;
    public static JTextField txtRollAmnt;
    public static JTextField txtUserName;
    public static JTextField txtStartBid;
    public static JTextField txtMultiplier;
    public static JTextField txtMinRemaining;
    public static JPasswordField txtPassword;
    public static JTextField txtOdds;
    public static JTextField txtMaxBet;
    public static JTextArea txtInfo;
    public static JCheckBox RollAmntCheck;
    public static JLabel lblBalTag;
    public static JLabel userTag;
    public static JLabel passTag;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    dicebot frame = new dicebot();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    Dicebotcode d = new Dicebotcode();
                    d.LoadSettings();
                    d = null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public dicebot() {
        setTitle("Dice Bot");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0};
        gbl_panel.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

        //Every new Label however needs every part that says "user" or on the Password: "pass" changed to something unique.
        userTag = new JLabel("Username:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_userTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_userTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_userTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_userTag.gridx = 0;//Here are your x + y coords
        gbc_userTag.gridy = 1;//Adding to x moves left, adding to y moves down
        panel.add(userTag, gbc_userTag);

        //Every new textfield needs only the * part to change for it to be valid. (gbc_* =)
          //textField = new JTextField();
        txtUserName = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints grdUserName = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdUserName.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdUserName.gridx = 1;
        grdUserName.gridy = 1;
        txtUserName.setColumns(10);
        panel.add(txtUserName, grdUserName);
        //panel.add(textField,txtUserName);
        //textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel balTag = new JLabel("Current Balance:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_balTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_balTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_balTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_balTag.gridx = 0;  
        gbc_balTag.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(balTag, gbc_balTag);

        lblBalTag = new JLabel("[________________]");
        lblBalTag.setToolTipText("Balance as of the last call to the peerbet site.");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblBalTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblBalTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_lblBalTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_lblBalTag.gridx = 1;
        gbc_lblBalTag.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(lblBalTag, gbc_lblBalTag);

        JLabel startTag = new JLabel("Starting Bid:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_startTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_startTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_startTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_startTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_startTag.gridy = 3;
        panel.add(startTag, gbc_startTag);

        txtStartBid = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints grdStartBid = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdStartBid.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdStartBid.gridx = 1;
        grdStartBid.gridy = 3;
        txtStartBid.setText("0.00000010");
        txtStartBid.setEnabled(false);
        panel.add(txtStartBid, grdStartBid);

        JLabel multTag = new JLabel("Multiplier:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_multTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_multTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_multTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_multTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_multTag.gridy = 4;
        panel.add(multTag, gbc_multTag);

        txtMultiplier = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints grdMultiplier = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdMultiplier.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdMultiplier.gridx = 1;
        grdMultiplier.gridy = 4;
        txtMultiplier.setColumns(10);
        txtMultiplier.setText("2");
        txtMultiplier.setEnabled(false);
        panel.add(txtMultiplier, grdMultiplier);

        JLabel minTag = new JLabel("Min Remaining:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_minTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_minTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_minTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_minTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_minTag.gridy = 5;
        panel.add(minTag, gbc_minTag);

        txtMinRemaining = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints grdMinRemaining = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdMinRemaining.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdMinRemaining.gridx = 1;
        grdMinRemaining.gridy = 5;
        txtMinRemaining.setColumns(10);
        txtMinRemaining.setText("0");
        txtMinRemaining.setEnabled(false);
        panel.add(txtMinRemaining, grdMinRemaining);

        txtPassword = new JPasswordField();
        GridBagConstraints grdPassword = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdPassword.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdPassword.gridx = 1;
        grdPassword.gridy = 2;
        txtPassword.setEchoChar('*');
        txtPassword.setColumns(10);
        panel.add(txtPassword, grdPassword);

        passTag = new JLabel("Password:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_passTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_passTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_passTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_passTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_passTag.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(passTag, gbc_passTag);

        txtOdds = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints grdOdds = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdOdds.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdOdds.gridx = 1;
        grdOdds.gridy = 6;
        txtOdds.setColumns(10);
        txtOdds.addActionListener(this);
        txtOdds.setText("49.5");
        txtOdds.setEnabled(false);
        panel.add(txtOdds, grdOdds);

        JLabel oddsTag = new JLabel("Odds %:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_oddsTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_oddsTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_oddsTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_oddsTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_oddsTag.gridy = 6;
        panel.add(oddsTag, gbc_oddsTag);

        txtMaxBet = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints grdMaxBet = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdMaxBet.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdMaxBet.gridx = 1;
        grdMaxBet.gridy = 7;
        txtMaxBet.setColumns(10);
        txtMaxBet.setText("1");
        txtMaxBet.setEnabled(false);
        panel.add(txtMaxBet, grdMaxBet);

    txtRollAmnt = new JTextField();
        GridBagConstraints grdRollAmnt = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdRollAmnt.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdRollAmnt.gridx = 1;
        grdRollAmnt.gridy = 8;
        txtRollAmnt.setColumns(10);
        txtRollAmnt.setText("0=Infinite");
        txtRollAmnt.setEnabled(false);
        panel.add(txtRollAmnt, grdRollAmnt);

    RollAmntCheck = new JCheckBox("Roll Then Quit:");   
        RollAmntCheck.setSelected(true);
    GridBagConstraints grdRollAmntCheck = new GridBagConstraints();
        grdRollAmntCheck.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        grdRollAmntCheck.gridx = 0;
        grdRollAmntCheck.gridy = 8;
        panel.add(RollAmntCheck, grdRollAmntCheck);

        //This is the Combo Box
        cmbCurrency = new JComboBox<String>(new String[]{"BTC","LTC","PPC","NMC","XPM","FTC","ANC","DOGE","NXT"});
        GridBagConstraints gbc_list = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_list.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_list.gridx = 1;
        gbc_list.gridy = 9;
        cmbCurrency.addActionListener(this);
        cmbCurrency.setEnabled(false);
        panel.add(cmbCurrency, gbc_list);

        JLabel maxTag = new JLabel("MaxBet:");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_maxTag = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_maxTag.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
        gbc_maxTag.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc_maxTag.gridx = 0;
        gbc_maxTag.gridy = 7;
        panel.add(maxTag, gbc_maxTag);

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        btnDonate = new JButton("Login");
        btnDonate.addActionListener(this);
        panel_1.add(btnDonate);

        btnHigh = new JButton("Roll High");
        btnHigh.addActionListener(this);
        btnHigh.setEnabled(false);
        panel_1.add(btnHigh);

        btnLow = new JButton("Roll Low");
        btnLow.addActionListener(this);
        btnLow.setEnabled(false);
        panel_1.add(btnLow);

        btnFloat = new JButton("Roll Float");
        btnFloat.addActionListener(this);
        btnFloat.setEnabled(false);
        btnFloat.setVisible(false);
        panel_1.add(btnFloat);

        btnClearLog = new JButton("Clear Log");
        btnClearLog.addActionListener(this);
        panel_1.add(btnClearLog);

        scrollCheck = new JCheckBox("Auto-Scroll"); 
        scrollCheck.setSelected(true);
        panel_1.add(scrollCheck);

        scrollDisable = new JCheckBox("Disable Log");   
        scrollDisable.setSelected(false);
        panel_1.add(scrollDisable);

        btnClearLog.setToolTipText("Click here to clear the log!");
        btnHigh.setToolTipText("Click here to Roll High!");
        btnLow.setToolTipText("Click here to Roll Low!");
        btnFloat.setToolTipText("Click here to Roll?");
        scrollCheck.setToolTipText("Toggles the auto-scroll function of the log.");
        RollAmntCheck.setToolTipText("Roll Amount then Quit");
        txtMaxBet.setToolTipText("The dicebot will not bet above amount entered in.");
        txtOdds.setToolTipText("What odds(%) will the dicebot be rolling?");
        txtPassword.setToolTipText("Enter your peerbet account password.");
        txtMinRemaining.setToolTipText("The bot will stop when account has less than this amount in bank.");
        txtMultiplier.setToolTipText("What shall the bet be multiplied by upon loss?");
        txtStartBid.setToolTipText("What amount should the bot start each bet at?");
        txtUserName.setToolTipText("Enter your peerbet account username.");
        lblBalTag.setToolTipText("Current amount of chosen currency shown here.");
        cmbCurrency.setToolTipText("Choose the currency that the bot will be using to roll with.");

         contentPane.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        txtInfo = new JTextArea("All number formats must use a period(.)\nBot By: MichaelAdair and DalinSprocket\n");
        txtInfo.setColumns(35);
        txtInfo.setEnabled(false);

    textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        textPane.setEditable(false);
        textPane.setMargin(null);
        textPane.setContentType("text/html");

    StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

        Style style = textPane.addStyle("Loss",null);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.red);

    Style style2 = textPane.addStyle("Win",null);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.green);
        pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == cmbCurrency) {
            if (cmbCurrency.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
                txtStartBid.setText("0.00000010");
            }else{
                txtStartBid.setText("0.0001");
            }
            if(APIKey != null){
                String balance = peerbetapi.get_balance(dicebot.APIKey);
                JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.readFrom(balance);
                if(jsonObject.get("status").asInt() == 1){
                    lblBalTag.setText(jsonObject.get("raffle_cur" + Integer.toString((cmbCurrency.getSelectedIndex() + 10))).asString());
                }
            }else{
                lblBalTag.setText("[________________]");
            }
        }else if (e.getSource() == btnLow){
            if(btnLow.getText() == "Roll Low"){
                btnHigh.setText("Stop");
                btnLow.setText("Stop On Win");
                btnFloat.setEnabled(false);
                Dicebotcode dbc = new Dicebotcode();
                Dicebotcode.RollType = "low";
                Dicebotcode.StopRollingOnWin = false;
                Dicebotcode.StopRolling = false;
                dbc.dbc();
            }else{
                // The EnableAllFields function will re-enable the buttons once its done.
                btnLow.setText("Waiting...");
                btnLow.setEnabled(false);
                Dicebotcode.StopRollingOnWin = true;
            }
        }else if (e.getSource() == btnHigh){
            if(btnHigh.getText() == "Roll High"){
                btnHigh.setText("Stop");
                btnLow.setText("Stop On Win");
                btnFloat.setEnabled(false);
                Dicebotcode dbc = new Dicebotcode();
                Dicebotcode.RollType = "high";
                Dicebotcode.StopRollingOnWin = false;
                Dicebotcode.StopRolling = false;
                dbc.dbc();
            }else{
                // The EnableAllFields function will re-enable the buttons once its done.
                btnHigh.setText("Stopping...");
                btnHigh.setEnabled(false);
                btnLow.setEnabled(false);
                Dicebotcode.StopRolling = true;
            }
        }else if (e.getSource() == btnFloat){
            if(btnFloat.getText() == "Roll Float"){
                btnHigh.setText("Stop");
                btnLow.setText("Stop On Win");
                btnFloat.setEnabled(false);
                Dicebotcode dbc = new Dicebotcode();
                Dicebotcode.RollType = "float";
                Dicebotcode.StopRollingOnWin = false;
                Dicebotcode.StopRolling = false;
                dbc.dbc();
            }else{
                // The EnableAllFields function will re-enable the buttons once its done.
                btnFloat.setText("Stopping...");
                btnFloat.setEnabled(false);
                Dicebotcode.StopRolling = true;
            }
        }else if (e.getSource() == btnClearLog){
            txtInfo.setText("");
        }else if (e.getSource() == btnDonate){
            //donate d = new donate();
            if(btnDonate.getText() == "Login"){
                String reply = null;
                try {
                    reply = peerbetapi.login(txtUserName.getText(), String.copyValueOf(txtPassword.getPassword()));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    reply = "{\"status\":0, \"message\":\"An unknown error has occurred while attempting to login.\"}";
                }
                JsonObject json = JsonObject.readFrom(reply);
                if(json.get("status").asInt() != 1){
                    txtInfo.append("Error: " + json.get("message").asString() + "\n");
                    txtInfo.setCaretPosition(txtInfo.getText().length());
                }else{
                    APIKey = json.get("key").asString();
                    lblBalTag.setText(json.get("raffle_cur" + Integer.toString(cmbCurrency.getSelectedIndex() + 10)).asString());
                    btnDonate.setText("Donate");
                    userTag.setVisible(false);
                    txtUserName.setVisible(false);
                    passTag.setVisible(false);
                    txtPassword.setVisible(false);
                    txtStartBid.setEnabled(true);
                    txtMultiplier.setEnabled(true);
                    txtMinRemaining.setEnabled(true);
                    txtOdds.setEnabled(true);
                    txtMaxBet.setEnabled(true);
                    cmbCurrency.setEnabled(true);
                    btnHigh.setEnabled(true);
                    btnLow.setEnabled(true);
                    btnFloat.setEnabled(true);
                    txtInfo.append("Login successful!\n");
                    txtInfo.setCaretPosition(txtInfo.getText().length());
                }
            }else{
                donate.showdonate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1086)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:966)
    at dicebot.<init>(dicebot.java:298)
    at dicebot$1.run(dicebot.java:44)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: `JTextArea` is suppose to entertain only plain text. Attributes set on a single word/character are used by whole Document. Though as stated in the answer `JTextPane/JEditorPane` is best suited for this need. One [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9651404/1057230) and another [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9652143/1057230)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 variables called style in one method. You cannot do this. Also you are not passing the correct number of arguments to addStyle.

See http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/JTextPaneStylesExample6.htm for a complete example of using JTextPane Styles:

```
/*
Core SWING Advanced Programming 
By Kim Topley
ISBN: 0 13 083292 8       
Publisher: Prentice Hall  
*/



import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class StylesExample6 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception evt) {}

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Styles Example 6");

    // Create the StyleContext, the document and the pane
    StyleContext sc = new StyleContext();
    final DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument(sc);
    final JTextPane pane = new JTextPane(doc);

    // Create and add the main document style
    Style defaultStyle = sc.getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);
    final Style mainStyle = sc.addStyle("MainStyle", defaultStyle);
    StyleConstants.setLeftIndent(mainStyle, 16);
    StyleConstants.setRightIndent(mainStyle, 16);
    StyleConstants.setFirstLineIndent(mainStyle, 16);
    StyleConstants.setFontFamily(mainStyle, "serif");
    StyleConstants.setFontSize(mainStyle, 12);

    // Create and add the constant width style
    final Style cwStyle = sc.addStyle("ConstantWidth", null);
    StyleConstants.setFontFamily(cwStyle, "monospaced");
    StyleConstants.setForeground(cwStyle, Color.green);

    // Create and add the heading style
    final Style heading2Style = sc.addStyle("Heading2", null);
    StyleConstants.setForeground(heading2Style, Color.red);
    StyleConstants.setFontSize(heading2Style, 16);
    StyleConstants.setFontFamily(heading2Style, "serif");
    StyleConstants.setBold(heading2Style, true);
    StyleConstants.setLeftIndent(heading2Style, 8);
    StyleConstants.setFirstLineIndent(heading2Style, 0);

    try {
      SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          try {
            // Set the logical style
            doc.setLogicalStyle(0, mainStyle);

            // Add the text to the document
            doc.insertString(0, text, null);

            // Apply the character attributes
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(49, 13, cwStyle, false);
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(223, 14, cwStyle, false);
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(249, 14, cwStyle, false);
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(286, 8, cwStyle, false);
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(475, 14, cwStyle, false);
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(497, 21, cwStyle, false);
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(557, 9, cwStyle, false);
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(639, 12, cwStyle, false);
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(733, 21, cwStyle, false);
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(759, 9, cwStyle, false);

            // Finally, apply the style to the heading
            doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, 1, heading2Style, false);

            // Set the foreground color and change the font
            pane.setForeground(Color.pink);
            pane.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.ITALIC, 24));
          } catch (BadLocationException e) {
          }
        }
      });
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception when constructing document: " + e);
      System.exit(1);
    }

    f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(pane));
    f.setSize(400, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static final String text = 
          "Attributes, Styles and Style Contexts\n" +
          "The simple PlainDocument class that you saw in the previous " + 
          "chapter is only capable of holding text. The more complex text " +
          "components use a more sophisticated model that implements the " +
          "StyledDocument interface. StyledDocument is a sub-interface of " +
          "Document that contains methods for manipulating attributes that " +
          "control the way in which the text in the document is displayed. " +
          "The Swing text package contains a concrete implementation of " +
          "StyledDocument called DefaultStyledDocument that is used as the " +
          "default model for JTextPane and is also the base class from which " +
          "more specific models, such as the HTMLDocument class that handles " +
          "input in HTML format, can be created. In order to make use of " +
          "DefaultStyledDocument and JTextPane, you need to understand how " +
          "Swing represents and uses attributes.\n";

}
```

Comment: See "What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: I still don't understand what I have to do... sorry, I'm kind of a noob to java...

Comment: The stack trace shows the error is at dicebot.java, line 298.

You need to post all of your source file if you want more help.

Comment: I added it... David. 298 is  contentPane.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

Comment: You call contentPane.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER); then a few lines later 
        txtInfo = new JTextArea("All number formats must use a period(.)\nBot By: MichaelAdair and DalinSprocket\n");
        txtInfo.setColumns(35);
        txtInfo.setEnabled(false);

    textPane = new JTextPane();

Comment: You call contentPane.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER), here textPane is null and add will throw NullPointerException. A few lines later you initialise textPane = new JTextPane();

Answer (score 3):

The color of the text has nothing to do with the JScrollPane. Use a text component that support multiple colors, such as JTextPane or JEditorPane. Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html

Comment: Like I said, the color of the text has nothing to do with the JScrollPane. You're calling functions on the JScrollPane that don't exist. Maybe you meant to call them on your text component?

Comment: Wait if I make it into a JTextPane will it still have the scroll function?

Comment: What happened when you tried? Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Create the correct type of text component. Which type is correct depends on exactly what you want. Call the appropriate methods on that text component. Add that text component to a JScrollPane.