# Setting multiple text colors in a String in a JTextArea

Tags: java, html, swing, colors

I am attempting to set multiple text colors for a `String` in a JTextArea. I have tried multiple things such as:

```
<html>Text color: <font color='red'>red</font><font color ="black">Hi</font></html>
<html>Text color: <font color="red">red</font><font color ="black">Hi</font></html>
```

But it just appears as that itself. I read things such as use JEditorPane or JTextPane and I thought of it but I'm unfamiliar with all the things that'd require to use. I'd have to learn it eventually but not now.

**EDIT: I have learned that you can't use colors on** `JTextArea`

Comment: JTextArea wont support html..JEditorPane is the only option and it's almost same as JTextArea .why bother using that

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.


I don't know if you mean the HTML of JTextArea but alas:

JTextArea I was introduced to first and it was mainly my go-to so I'm very familiar with it. 


As for the HTML, well, I'm familiar with it (vaguely) but mainly due to being familiar with JTextArea so much. @Madhan

Comment: JTextArea only supports plain text, you can use JTextPane wch supports a styled document or a JEditorPane which can support a HTML document

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) for more options

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650992/how-to-change-text-color-in-the-jtextarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `JTextArea` cannot be used for that. It supports only and only plain text. Whatever `HTML` you write in it, will appear as it is.

As an alternative, you can either use `JTextPane` or `JEditorPane`.

Check docs:

JTextPane: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html

JEditorPane:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html