# String variable activity to set color as red to display on jtextarea

Tags: java

I want to display value from variable "activity" to red color, "activity" value I got form MySQL database. Is that possible to set color on String Activity? If it is possible can you show me how to make it?

```
public void Select()
{
    int n = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberRow; i++) {
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atm?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
            String validate = "SELECT * FROM history WHERE UserActivityID LIKE '" + n +  "'";
            PreparedStatement smtm = con.prepareStatement(validate);
            ResultSet rs = smtm.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                String Time = rs.getString("UserTimeActivity");
                String activity = rs.getString("UserActivity");
                n++;
                jTextAreaActivity.append(activity + " - " + Time + "\n");
            }
        } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException | ClassCastException  ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change text color in the JtextArea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650992/how-to-change-text-color-in-the-jtextarea)

Comment: you use prepared statement and `'" + n +  "'` ? 

Comment: oh that one,, i do looping , just for counter

Comment: @AriffNaj inefficient, it will result in multiple SQL plan being parsed. A bind parameter for `n` should reuse the plan if the driver caches correctly.