# Is there an equivalent to android SpannableString in Java SDK

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the text of one word in a sentence and populate it to a JTextArea (Java Swing).

I have tried splitting the sentence based on white space to an array of words:

```
String[] words = message_textArea.getText().split(" ");
```

Then finding the starting and ending index of my word to use with SpannableString , but this only appears to be available with the android SDK.

Is there a alternative to the SpannableString in the java SDK?
If not is there a means to change the colour of one word in a sentence in the java SDK?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change text color in the JTextArea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650992/how-to-change-text-color-in-the-jtextarea)

Comment: Not quite, I had a look at the post, this is more detail on my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58984995/jtextpane-cannot-render-a-concatenated-hmtl-string

Comment: I used solution for my issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58991762/html-wrapped-string-creates-a-unwanted-new-line-in-jtextpane-output