# HTML wrapped String creates a unwanted new line in JtextPane output

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, htmleditorkit

When I concentrate a String with a HTML formatted string, and output the String to a JTextPane with a 
HTMLEditor kit, every appended String wrapped in the HTML tags appears to cause a new line:

```
// Set the HTML Editor kit for JTExtPAne
    jtextPane.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());

        String  saveCurrentSentenceState = "Some String";
        String newWord = "new word"; // wrap this in HTML tags

        // Create a HTML String
        String appendHTML = "<html><font color=\"red\">"+newWord+"<</font>";

        // Concatenate with an existing String
        saveCurrentSentenceState += " " + appendHTML;

        jtextPane.setText(appendHTML);
```

Output in the JTextPane has unwanted line breaks where each HTML String has been concatenated:

[image]

Expected output would be all the words in a single line:

> hello gello top top hello

This is the string printed to the console:

```
 hello gello <html><font color="red">top<</font> <html><font color="red">top<</font> hello
```

I have tried trimming the string but same output:

```
saveCurrentSentenceState.trim();
```

As I append the String with a HTML formatted sub string, I do not close the HTML tag, as any concatenated string after a closed HTML tag does not print.

Is there anyway I can stop this newline form printing ?

Comment: Cannot understand your question. Please provide a [mcve] and specify your actual and desired behavior, so we can easier understand what you've asked.

Comment: Have added more information, hopefully a bit clearer

Comment: Use `Document` interface to append your text. Something like `jtextPane.getDocument().insertString(jtextPane.getDocument.getLength(), "my text", myFormatAttributes)`

Comment: Doesn’t work as my concentrated strings contain a mixture of HTML formatted words with non HTML formatted strings

Comment: Have you tried to remove `<html>` and `</html>` tags from your string and insert your text before the closing `</html>` from the text pane?

Comment: *Have added more information, hopefully a bit clearer* - no, we are still waiting for your [mre]. You need a frame with a JtextPane with default text. Then you add a button that when clicked will attempt to insert the HTML. Then we can see exactly what you are doing. We have no idea what your "mixture of HTML formatted words with non HTML" looks like.

Comment: As an aside to the sage advice already offered, but harking mostly back to a comment by @SergiyMedvynskyy. This `hello gello <html><font color="red">top<</font> <html><font color="red">top<</font> hello` is ***not*** HTML. At least not *valid* HTML. How the editor pane (or any HTML client) renders it is .. at best 'undefined'. Before slapping it into an editor pane, [validate the 'HTML'](https://validator.w3.org) string.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy yes that works, i removed the <HTML> tags, can you post as an answer , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you inserts the incorrect HTML (as it was mentioned in the comment of @AndrewThompson). The easiest way in your case to get the correct result is to remove all `<html>` and `</html>` tags from your strings, then merge these strings and append `<html>` and `</html>` after that. In this case you'll get the correct HTML, that can be processed by the `HTMLEditorKit` of `JTextPane`